# Calling a function in another component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, components, ionic3

I have created a component called AccordionComponent for Ionic/Angular Apps. Here is the Component Class.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, Renderer, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'accordion',
  templateUrl: 'accordion.html'
})
export class AccordionComponent implements OnInit {

  accordionExapanded = false;
  @ViewChild("cc") cardContent: any;
  @Input('title') title: string;

  icon: string = "arrow-forward";

  constructor(public renderer: Renderer) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.cardContent.nativeElement);
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.cardContent.nativeElement, "webkitTransition", "max-height 500ms, padding 500ms");
  }

  close(){
       if (this.accordionExapanded) {
      this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.cardContent.nativeElement, "max-height", "0px");
      this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.cardContent.nativeElement, "padding", "0px 16px");
this.accordionExapanded = !this.accordionExapanded;
        this.icon = this.icon == "arrow-forward" ? "arrow-down" : "arrow-forward";

    }
  }

  toggleAccordion() {
    if (this.accordionExapanded) {
      this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.cardContent.nativeElement, "max-height", "0px");
      this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.cardContent.nativeElement, "padding", "0px 16px");

    } else {
      this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.cardContent.nativeElement, "max-height", "500px");
      this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.cardContent.nativeElement, "padding", "13px 16px");

    }

    this.accordionExapanded = !this.accordionExapanded;
    this.icon = this.icon == "arrow-forward" ? "arrow-down" : "arrow-forward";

  }

}
```

I use this component using a ngFor in my Page like this,

```
<accordion *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index" [title]="user.name">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        Email: {{ user.email }}
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        Phone {{ user.phone }}
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        Website {{ user.website }}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

  </accordion>
```

I am unable to find a way to close all other accordions when one is expanded. I need to call the close() function for all Accordions once an Accordion is expanded. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You have many accordions(components), or you meant the items?

Comment: I have multiple accordion components, which are created using ngFor.

Comment: You are trying to listen events from <ng-content> which you can't. The only way is to use common service. Can you show the accordion.html too?

Comment: Well, I misunderstood your question. It's not about ng-content. You gotta communicate through parent component as  @Vega mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your accordion component should listen some input from parent component to decide whether it is gonna be closed or opened. Since your accordions are generated dynamically by *ngFor, you are better to pass the data by using our user items.

```
 export class AccordionComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

   @Input('accordionExpanded') accordionExpanded = false;     

   ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
      if(changes.hasOwnProperty('accordionExpanded')){
         this.accordionExpanded ? this.openAccordion() : this.closeAccordion();
      }
   }     
}
```

and the parent component listens all off generated accordion clicks and informs all accordions with a parameter inside user.

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit{
    public users:Array<CustomUserType> = [];

    ngOnInit() {
       this.users.forEach(u => u.accordionExpanded = false);
    } 

    onClickAccordion(user){
      this.users.forEach(u => u.accordionExpanded = false);
      user.accordionExpanded = true;
   } 
 }     

 export interface CustomUserType extends YourUserType{
     accordionExpanded:boolean;
 }
```

and this is template

```
<accordion *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index" [title]="user.name" (click)="onClickAccordion(user)" [accordionExpanded]="user.accordionExpanded">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        Email: {{ user.email }}
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        Phone {{ user.phone }}
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        Website {{ user.website }}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

  </accordion>
```

Comment: I am understanding this a little bit, I will try to implement this and post back. Thanks.

Comment: Wonderful. Worked like a charm. Could please explain to me the code where you have used `ngOnChanges`? What is `ngOnChanges` &  `SimpleChanges`?

Answer (score 1):

Change accordionExapanded to @Input with a setter. When an accordion gets the click, emit event (@Output this time) to parent to set others accordionExapanded to false. Also, in the setter call close() or toggle() based on accordionExapanded value. Remove accordionExapanded=!accordionExapanded from close() and toggle().